# My animation is not working in this slider which I made using html, css, js

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui-slider, codepen

```
<https://codepen.io/samyakjain20/pen/dyMmaYj>
```

This is what I tried!, tried to integrate two slider designs mentioned below. The gesture animation which is there in the 1st link is not working in my slider.

```
https://codepen.io/codewunder/pen/Bnspb/

https://codepen.io/maheshambure21/pen/qZZrxy
```

I think the error is in JavaScript but I don't know how to solve. If you have seen something similar to this then also please mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just click in the cog icon on the JavaScript panel, and add the jQuery CDN link `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js`

This error is because the jQuery library is not found in your code.

[image]

Comment: How can I use it on my local pc

Comment: To solve this just add the cdn link as shown in the picture above. In the JavaScript panel, click in the cog icon, then paste the link present in my answer. That's it! To run locally you need to import the jQuery cdn link in you html as well.